# Can append to file using Java class but not using Java Servlet

Tags: java, csv, servlets

I have a client-server model, wherein the client is filling a form, and the server saves the form data into a .csv file. Here is the code I'm using to write to the csv:

```
        String fileName="responses.csv";

        File f = new File(fileName);

        PrintWriter toFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true)));

        toFile.println("test1,test2,\"test3,test4\"");//test code
        toFile.close();
```

I have a Java Servlet (javax.servlet-API 3.1.0) and a Tester.java class in a package. Tester.java has a `main()` method in it, which executes the above code and then terminates.

When I run this code in the Tester, it works fine and the csv is written as expected.

However, in my Servlet, **the file is not written.** I do not see any Exception to indicate that I have an access issue. Since both .java files are in the same package, they can both access my csv file.

Note that my main() method terminates after file writing whereas my Servlet does not.

Why is my servlet not able to write to file ? Any guidance is earnestly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Filesystem permissions are not related to Java access control -- two classes being in the same package has nothing to do with whether they can access the same files.

Comment: Nevertheless, if there is no exception then the most likely explanation is that the servlet *does* write to the file, but the file is not where you expect it to be.  You're using a relative file name, which will be resolved with respect to the VM's current working directory.  That is likely to be quite different when you run a servlet engine in the VM than when you run your own test application.

Comment: Another possibility is that the code you present is not reached in your servlet.  You haven't presented enough of an example for us to evaluate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the file created actually exists and what permissions you see. Try to save the csv file on a path where the user has write permission.

Also, if there is no error, print the absolute path for the file to see where it got written to.

Comment: While my Tester class was writing to the csv located in my project directory, My servlet was writing to a csv in the location of my eclipse setup. Printing the absolute paths helped. Thanks

Comment: Glad that helped!